React-devtools menu view source for React element does not work
I am running a React Vite app.
I installed React developers tools (5.2.0 - 5/8/2024) in Chrome last version.
I go to Components menu and I can see my React component Alert in App.
But when I click on the menu View source for this element nothing happen.

And when I go to Sources menu the source of the component is not displayed.

Any idea what is the problem?
